# How do I don't validate a nested class in FluentValidation MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, fluentvalidation

I have a Viewmodel that have another Viewmodel inside, take a look

```
 [Validator(typeof(ParentValidatorVM))]
public class ParentVM {
        public ChildVM { get; set; }
        public ParentVM () {
        this.ChildVM = new ChildVM ();
     }
}
//rulles for validation
internal sealed class ParentValidatorVM : AbstractValidator<ParentVM> {
        public ParentValidatorVM() {
        //set rules
        this.RuleFor(x => x.ChildVM).NotValidate();
            //the row above is just an example the method 'NotValidate', I invented   

       }
}
```

The ChildVM has the structure with properties

```
     [Validator(typeof(ChildValidatorVM))]
public class ChildVM {
       //My properties
}
//rulles for validation
internal sealed class ChildValidatorVM : AbstractValidator<ChildVM> {
        public ChildValidatorVM() {
        //set rules
       }
}
```

My problem is, when I call `ModelState.isValid` the rules from the child comes together the rules from the Parent, it is not to happen.
Someone know a way to avoid it?